# How to Graph y = x/x in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I have not been able to find an answer to the seemingly simple question of how to graph the function f(x) = x/x as a *Tikzpicture*, identifying the missing point (0, 1) with an open circle, and appropriately labeling x and y-axes.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't f(x) = x/x always be equal to 1? And that would be a horizontal line y=1

Comment: @3kstc not really. It has a discontinuity at `x=0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**:
For a more general solution, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564698/125871).

You can just overlay a small circle at the appropriate coordinate:

[image]

I plotted the axes after the circle to make the y-axis visible inside the hole.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1] (-3,1) -- (3,1);
  \draw[line width=1,fill=white] (0,1) circle (.8mm);
  \draw[->] (-3, 0) -- (3, 0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, -3) -- (0, 3) node[above] {$y$};
  \node at (2,1.4) {$f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$};
  \node[below left] at (0,0) {0};
  \node[below left] at (0,1) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[blue, thick,  mark=none] {x/x};
  \draw[blue, thick, fill=white] (0,1) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot with circle]