# Easiest way to draw an upper semicontinuous function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to create something like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Upper_semi.svg/1920px-Upper_semi.svg.png):

[image]

What is the easiest way to do so?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  We generally prefer that questions focus on a narrow aspect, not "create an image".  Have you looked at various drawing capabilities of TeX?  Are you able to produce most of the image?  What part is still giving you trouble?  JohnKormylo has suggested a useful command using the TikZ package; I would encourage you to read some about it.

Comment: Use pgfplots with `\draw[blue] (axis cs: x,y) circle[radius=2pt];` or \fill for a solid circle..  A gap can be created with a missing entry in a table, or by repeating a specified color with `\addplot[color=blue]...`

Comment: I can draw a continuous function like x^2+3*x^5 but am totally clueless about how to to create such a jump.

Comment: Also I dont have to draw a specific function with such a jump. I just need to create an arbitrary example inclusing such a jump. So should I look into GeoGebra?

Comment: Assuming your function is to be graphed between -5 and +5, following x^2 if x<1 and 2+x^2 if x>=1. You just have to draw the first part, on domain [-5:1] and the second part on domain [1:5]. Then drawing your circles, one filled, the other not. Pretty straightforward if you know how to graph a function.

Comment: Have a look at (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564698/125871)

Comment: @Sandy G <3<3<3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `\piecewise` function from [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564698/125871), you can pick suitable functions. I chose x^2 and 2x–x^2.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\piecewise}[1]{
   \foreach \f/\a/\b/\open/\closed in {#1}{%
      \draw[domain=\a:\b, smooth, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, \f);
      \foreach \x[evaluate={\y=\f;}] in \open{%
         \draw[fill=white] (\x,\y) circle (.6mm);
      }
      \foreach \x[evaluate={\y=\f;}] in \closed{%
         \fill (\x,\y) circle (.6mm);
      }
   }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-stealth] (-2, 0) -- (3.5, 0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[-stealth] (0, -1.5) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[fill] (.6,0) circle(.6mm) node[below, yshift=-1] {$x_0$};
\begin{scope}[line width=1pt, blue]
\piecewise{{\x*\x}/-1.5/.6/{.6}/{},{2*\x-\x*\x}/.6/2.5/{}/{.6}}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```